# Is it possible to have optionally empty Snakemake wildcards?

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to have optionally empty wildcards? It seems like it was possible a few years ago (https://groups.google.com/g/snakemake/c/S7fTL4jAYIM), but the described method didn't work for a user last year and now is not working for me.

My Snakefile looks something like this (abbreviated for clarity):

```
wildcard_constraints:
    udn_id="ID.+",
    compound="(no_)*compound(_genome|_exome)*"

rule all:
    input: expand("file/path/{id}/{compound}{.*}.html",
            id=[config["id"]], compound=compound_list, freq=freq_list)

rule create_html:
    output: "file/path/{id}/{compound}{freq,.*}.html"
    input: "/oak/stanford/groups/euan/UDN/output/AnnotSV/AnnotSV_3.0.5/{udn_id}/WGS_blood_"+hg+"/gateway_hpo/{udn_id}.{comp_het}{cohort_freq,.*}.annotated.tsv"
    shell: #Run shell commands

rule append_freq:
    output: "file/path/{id}/{compound}.ha_freq.tsv"
    input: "file/path/{id}/{compound}.tsv"
    script: "file/path/get_ha_freq.py"
```

I get the error

```
No values given for wildcard ''.
File file/path, line 6 in <module>
```

when I run this.

I also tried implementing a wildcard constraint like this:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    udn_id="ID.+",
    compound="(no_)*compound(_genome|_exome)*"
    freq=".*"

rule all:
    input: expand("file/path/{id}/{compound}{freq}.html",
            id=[config["id"]], compound=compound_list, freq=freq_list)

rule create_html:
    output: "file/path/{id}/{compound}{freq}.html"
    input: "/oak/stanford/groups/euan/UDN/output/AnnotSV/AnnotSV_3.0.5/{udn_id}/WGS_blood_"+hg+"/gateway_hpo/{udn_id}.{comp_het}{cohort_freq}.annotated.tsv"
    shell: #Run shell commands

rule append_freq:
    output: "file/path/{id}/{compound}.ha_freq.tsv"
    input: "file/path/{id}/{compound}.tsv"
    script: "file/path/get_ha_freq.py"
```

but I received the error,

```
No values given for wildcard 'freq'.
File file/path, line 7 in <module>
```

when I did this.

What error am I making?

Comment: Traditionally this has worked by using a wildcard constraint of ".*". Are you saying that this method no longer works? It would help if you shared a simple reproducible example.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you mean by "optionally empty wildcards" (preferably with a concrete example) and the approach that is not working for you?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had added the link to the previous question. I added that link for reference, as well as my use case.

Comment: Snakemake would normally tell you which line was causing the error. Please provide this information.

Comment: @RobertDavy, I've added the line numbers in to indicate the lines in my abbreviated code that are causing the issue.

Comment: So the error is in the expand function. It has nothing to do with the wildcard constraint. In fact, in the expand function you could replace {freq} with some other variable to avoid confusion.
What are the type and contents of freq_list ? 
What happens if you replace the expand function with its list comprehension equivalent?
Is this the exact script you are running? I would expect no comma on line 3 would give a syntax error.

Comment: @RobertDavy Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up setting freq_list = [config["freq"]] (and added the missing comma) and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to have empty wildcards if you update the `wildcard_constraints` as described in your link. Here's a short example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env snakemake

wildcard_constraints:
  sample=".*"

samples = ["a", "b", "", "d"]

rule all:
  input:
    "collected/all_samples.txt"

rule process_samples:
  output:
    "processed/{sample}.txt"
  shell:
    """
    echo '{wildcards.sample}' > {output}
    """

rule collect_samples:
  input:
    processed = ["processed/{}.txt".format(sample) for sample in samples]
  output:
    "collected/all_samples.txt"
  shell:
    """
    cat {input.processed} > {output}
    """
```

After saving this file as `example.smk` I can run the pipeline:

```
$ snakemake --cores 1 -s example.smk
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job                count    min threads    max threads
---------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                    1              1              1
collect_samples        1              1              1
process_samples        4              1              1
total                  6              1              1


[Wed Aug 25 20:43:24 2021]
rule process_samples:
    output: processed/a.txt
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: sample=a
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Aug 25 20:43:24 2021]
Finished job 2.
1 of 6 steps (17%) done

[Wed Aug 25 20:43:24 2021]
rule process_samples:
    output: processed/.txt
    jobid: 4
    wildcards: sample=
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

... (skipping some output) ...

[Wed Aug 25 20:43:25 2021]
localrule all:
    input: collected/all_samples.txt
    jobid: 0
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Aug 25 20:43:25 2021]
Finished job 0.
6 of 6 steps (100%) done
```

The empty wildcard output file `processed.txt` is created at the empty wildcard (line) is present in the `collected/all_samples.txt` file.

```
$ ls processed/.txt
processed/.txt
$ cat collected/all_samples.txt
a
b

d
```